# How to remove slash from image ng-src url?

Tags: angularjs

I get an error 400 from the images server provider because the request include slash in the end of the image url

```
    <div class="footer accordian" ng-hide="photosSlider">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div class="image_title">
                <a href="#">KungFu Panda</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
                <img ng-src={{item.img}}/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The items array, holds images url without slash in the tail of the url
[image]

When Angular send request for the image somehow slash added to the url
[image]

Any idea why the slash added and how to remove?

Comment: Are you using a PHP template?

Comment: `str.substring(0, str.length - 1)` with this you can trim last character.

Comment: I can't cut the tail, as you can see the array have the url without slash, somehow the slash added later while the request.

Comment: I get the urls from Facebook and save into array, I don't use PHP template unless I did't without notice, how to check?

Comment: I found the issue :), I forgot to add "", instead of <img ng-src={{item.img}}/> should be <img ng-src="{{item.img}}"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the / from inside the ng-repeat itself.
Use this

```
<img ng-src={{item.img.substring(0, item.img.length - 1)}}/>
```

Comment: I am not sure this way of coding is valid, I get code error

Comment: attribute item.img.length is not allowed here